# Input type file no file chosen after submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I've just upload the file in the input type file, and when the value of the form are submitted, the input type file still empty 
I emphasize that in my data base and my storage folder I have the registration line and the file.

[image]

```html
<!-- my form-->
<form role="form" action="/infos/update" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
 <label for="cin" class="control-label"> charger votre CNIE recto-verso en format pdf</label>
 <!--input type file -->  
 <input name="pdfcine" type="file" accept="application/pdf" class="form-control underlined" required="required" value="{{$user->cineface1}}">
   <div class="clearfix"></div></br>
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url('/').'/storage/'. $user->cineface1 }}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>Download Cine</a>

         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
           </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for someone to answer your question, you need to provide code samples. Please see the SO guide on how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello junaid Ahmad I'm newer in Stack Overflow ,

Comment: Don't worry almost everyone gets this kind of responses to their first question on stackoverflow. Just read the documentation on how to ask a question and you will be fine. :)

Comment: i ve just edit my question  I hope that it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

You must include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` with form action.

Comment: i ve just edit my question I hope that it's clearer – soukaina just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

You must be able to retrieve the file using either:

$request->file('pdfcine'); or
Input::get('pdfcine');